# Can't access ec2 webserver

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using an ec2 instance with windows 2012 just installed Apache 2.4 with an elastic IP.
I can log on using Remote desktop just fine. We can access the webserver locally using localhost but we cannot access it from outside. We have even tried opening up all ports and all IPs to make sure we didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: Did you check both the EC2 security group and the Windows firewall?

Comment: Ya, it was windows firewall.... We usually run ubuntu servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WE have worked with Linux servers like Ubuntu in the past on EC2 instances. Even though we are familiar with AWS Firewall and Security Groups we did miss that Windows has its own Firewall. Changing the Windows Firewall rules was the solution.